# jQuery validate on button click (not submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read all the solutions here and on other pages and can not find one that applies to my situation. Apologies in advance if there is one.

I am using jQuery .validate. I have some tabs that are dynamically loaded. So I can not use "submit". When I click the "Update" button I want to validate the input and then submit if valid.

The relevant code snippets are:

The dynamic load:

```
// class="tab-pane" is required.
            contents += '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + obj.eventId + '">';
            contents += '<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="tabForm'+obj.eventId+'">';
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';

            //Column 1
            contents += '<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">';

            //Location of Camp
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="location'+obj.eventId+'">Location of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="location'+obj.eventId+'" name="location" placeholder="Location of Camp" value="' + obj.eventLocation + '">';
            contents += '</div>';
```

Button:

```
contents += '<button id="'+obj.eventId+'" class="btn btn-large btn-primary update-button" type="button">Update</button>';
```

The validation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.update-button', function(){
            alert("Update"); //Is fired
            var formName = "#tabform" + this.id;
            $(formName).validate({
                //debug: true,
                rules: {
                    location: {
                        required: true
                    },
                },

                messages: {
                    location: {
                        required: "Please select enter a location."
                    },
                },

                submitHandler : function(formName) {
                    alert('updateCampFunction');

                    alert('this.id: ' + this.id);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('ssCampID', this.id);

                    var dataToBeSent  = {
                            ssCampID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssCampID'),
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "UpdateCampView",
                        data : dataToBeSent,
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                    })
                    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured updating the Camp');
                    })
                    .done(function(responseJson1a) {
                        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Updated.');

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Note that I am adding "obj.eventId" to make each form unique. There are no errors in the console.

Full js:

```
for(var i = 0; i < responseJson1a.length; i++) {
            var obj = responseJson1a[i];
            // class="tab-pane" is required.
            contents += '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + obj.eventId + '">';
            contents += '<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="tabForm'+obj.eventId+'">';
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';

            //Column 1
            contents += '<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">';

            //Dates of Camp
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            //Start Date
            var dateStart = moment(obj.eventDateStart).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
            contents += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">';
            contents += '<div class="form-group">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" for="startDate'+obj.eventId+'">Start Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">';
            contents += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate'+obj.eventId+'" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" value="' + dateStart + '">';
            contents += '<span class="input-group-addon">';
            contents += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>';
            contents += '</span>';
            contents += '</div>';
            contents += '</div>';
            contents += '</div>';
            //End Date
            var dateEnd = moment(obj.eventDateEnd).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
            contents += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">';
            contents += '<div class="form-group">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" for="endDate'+obj.eventId+'">End Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker2">';
            contents += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate'+obj.eventId+'" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date" value="' + dateEnd + '">';
            contents += '<span class="input-group-addon">';
            contents += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>';
            contents += '</span>';
            contents += '</div>';
            contents += '</div>';
            contents += '</div>';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Location of Camp
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="location'+obj.eventId+'">Location of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 location" type="text" id="location'+obj.eventId+'" name="location" placeholder="Location of Camp" value="' + obj.eventLocation + '" required>';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Details of Camp
            contents += '<div>';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="details'+obj.eventId+'">Details of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '</div>';
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<textarea class="summernote" id="details'+obj.eventId+'" name="details" rows="3">' + obj.eventDetails + '</textarea>';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Nights in camp
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="nights'+obj.eventId+'">Nights in Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="nights'+obj.eventId+'" name="nights" placeholder="Nights in Camp" value="' + obj.eventNights + '">';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Night in a building
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="building'+obj.eventId+'">Nights in a building:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="building'+obj.eventId+'" name="building" placeholder="Nights in a building" value="' + obj.eventNightsBuilding + '">';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Nights under canvas
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="canvas'+obj.eventId+'">Nights under canvas:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="canvas'+obj.eventId+'" name="canvas" placeholder="Nights under canvas" value="' + obj.eventNightsCanvas + '">';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Actual KM travelled
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="actualKM'+obj.eventId+'">Kilometres Travelled:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="actualKM'+obj.eventId+'" name="actualKM" placeholder="Kilometres Travelled" value="' + obj.eventKmActual + '">';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Offset for mode of travel
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="offset'+obj.eventId+'">Offset:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="offset'+obj.eventId+'" name="offset" placeholder="Offset" value="' + obj.eventKmOffset + '">';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Outcome
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="outcome'+obj.eventId+'">Outcome:</label>';
            contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="outcome'+obj.eventId+'" name="outcome" placeholder="Outcome" value="' + obj.eventKm + '" disabled>';
            contents += '</div>';

            //Process buttons
            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            contents += '<button id="'+obj.eventId+'" class="btn btn-large btn-primary update-button" type="button">Update</button>';
            contents += '<button id="'+obj.eventId+'" class="btn btn-large btn-primary delete-button" type="button">Delete</button>';
            contents += '</div>';

            contents += '</div>';//End of column 1

            //Column 2 to contain the image
            contents += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="'+obj.eventId+'">Photograph:</label>';
            contents += '<input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 photo-input" type="file" id="'+obj.eventId+'" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">';
            contents += '<img id="campImage'+obj.eventId+'" src="' + obj.eventPicture + '" alt="Camp image" class="img-thumbnail">';
            contents += '</div>';

            contents += '</div>';
            contents += '</form>';
            contents += '</div>';

            $("#tabContent").append(contents);
            contents = '';
        }
```

Comment: Can you think of any possible alternatives to using onclick? I would strongly discourage against using onclick because then the form couldn't be submitted via return key on input focus. You would be bypassing standard accessibility and functionality

Comment: Please, if you have a better way please let me know. I prefer to keep to the standards.

Comment: So even if the tab is dynamically loaded why wouldn't you be able to use 'submit' event?

Answer (score 0):

`var formName = "#tabform" + this.id;`  is `#tabform123456` but markup has an ID of `tabForm`

Comment: Good spot. I correct ed the "f" to "F"; however still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below
I added the rules **dynamically** to your **dynamic** content
Hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '.update-button', function(){
  var formName = "#tabForm" + this.id;
  $(formName).validate();
  $("input").each(function() { //replace selector with relevant data
   $(this).rules("add",
   {
       required: true,
       messages: {
       required: "This field is required" //replace text with dynamic data if needed
       }
   });
  });

  if($(formName).validate().form()) {
   console.log('Validated.');
   //this is where you do your ajax
  } else {
   console.log("Form not validated.");
  }
 });
 
 function BuildHTML(){ //hard-coded appender just for this example
  obj = {'eventId':123}; 
  var contents = '';
  contents += '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + obj.eventId + '">';
  contents += '<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="tabForm'+obj.eventId+'">';
  contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';

  //Column 1
  contents += '<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">';

  //Location of Camp
  contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
  contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="location'+obj.eventId+'">Location of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
  contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="location'+obj.eventId+'" name="location" placeholder="Location of Camp">';
  contents += '<br>';
  contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="location'+obj.eventId+'">Another Field:<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
  contents += '<input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="anotherField'+obj.eventId+'" name="anotherField" placeholder="Sample Placeholder">';
  contents += '</div>';
  contents += '<button id="'+obj.eventId+'" class="btn btn-large btn-primary update-button" type="button">Update</button>';
  
  $('#content').append(contents);
 }
 
 BuildHTML();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent! Almost there. The filed is validated; however, "This field is required." is displayed not "Please enter a location.". Also, I have nine fields to validate so is there a better way to put the rules in? And, finally, how do I trigger the update when valid?

Comment: Sure. I have edited my answer and I put comments to further help you with the issue and to understand how to adjust to what the project needs. I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: You are very helpful, thank you. I now get a console error. I have narrowed it down to when the each loop is completed this error is displayed "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
    at m.fn.init.rules (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (camp.js:271)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (camp.js:269)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)" for this line ".settings,e=d.rules,f=a.validator."

Comment: Run this code for me `$('[id]').each(function(){
  var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
    console.warn('Multiple IDs #'+this.id);
});` ... perhaps you have elements with same id

Comment: I made the code run-able so you can see it does not produce an error with the code I provided ... if there are any problems beyond the scope of this question I think it should be written/addressed in a different question

Comment: OK, this is where I am coming undone. In my readings I, mistakenly as it appears, read that .validate used the name not the id. I have now included the full dynamic html. And no id is not unique. When I run your test it shows duplicates on id and not on name.

Comment: OK, so I used "$("input").each(function() {" and displayed the id, commented out summernote because that was returning some blank id. I then had unique id (startDate23, endDate23, ....., outcome23, 23, startDate24) then it stopped. "startDate24 should not display as it is on the next tab. So I need to restrict this to check only the current tab.

Comment: I have been doing further testing. I Update on the first, of three, tabs, error. Move to second and Update, error. Move to third tab and Update, no error. Try each of the other two tabs, no error.

Comment: The error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
    at m.fn.init.rules (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (camp.js:305)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (camp.js:302)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
rules @ jquery.validate.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ camp.js:305
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ camp.js:302
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3"

Comment: I see, so my assumption was correct...you stated that your code produces duplicate IDs ... this is why your jQuery is printing error ... it is important to know that the error you are receiving is because of the duplicate IDs (as made clear and stated by your comment earlier) ... fix the duplication and the error will go away ... if not: perhaps the html might be badly formatted. let me know what happens

Comment: No. I used a workaround by placing validation in the HTML. I would like to get the validation working correctly though. I will keep you updated. 